# Unable to download html file and PDF file simultaneously from two different button click in angular 8 web API controller

Tags: angular, controller, webapi

I have 2 buttons one for downloading PDF File and another for downloading HTML File.

when we are clicking on the link to download html then the html file is being downloaded correctly, but after that when we are clicking on PDF file link then corrupted PDF is being downloaded. Same is happening vice-versa. (From both the links which will be clicked first, file of that link will download correctly.)

**Web API Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ExportPDFFile/{docId}")]
public IActionResult ExportPDFFile(string docId)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the file path
        string submissionFilePath = 
        Path.Combine(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<string> 
        ("SubmissionDataPath"), docId + ".pdf");

        // Send file to client
        Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(submissionFilePath);
            if (stream == null)
            {
                return NotFound(); // returns a NotFoundResult with Status404NotFound response.
            }

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SendExceptionEmail(ex);
        _logger.LogError("{0}\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        throw;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Return the Submission document from the file store
/// </summary>
/// <param name="docId"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet]
[Route("exportHTMLFile/{docId}")]
public IActionResult exportHTMLFile(string docId)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the file path
        string submissionHTMLFilePath = 
        Path.Combine(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<string> 
        ("SubmissionDataHTMLPath"), docId + ".html");

        // Send file to client
        Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(submissionHTMLFilePath);  
            if (stream == null)
            {
                return NotFound(); // returns a NotFoundResult with Status404NotFound response.
            }
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SendExceptionEmail(ex);
        _logger.LogError("{0}\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        throw;
    }
}
```

**app-service.ts**

```
exportPDFFile(id) {
  let apiUrl = window.location.href + 'Submission/ExportPDFFile/' + id;
  let httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  //'Authorization': 'jwt-token'
}),
responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
};

 return this._http.get<string>(apiUrl, httpOptions);
}

 exportHTMLFile(id) {

    let apiUrl = window.location.href + 'Submission/exportHTMLFile/' + id;
    let httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        //'Authorization': 'jwt-token'
    }),
    responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
};

return this._http.get<string>(apiUrl, httpOptions);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Cordova CLI to version >=4.2.0 npm install -g cordova.
This solved my issue